# Не изменяются координаты QGraphicsItem после перемещения

Tags: c++, qt, редактор, координаты

Мне необходимо реализовать функцию масштабирования элементов QGraphicsItem на сцене.

Я решил сделать это простым добавлением нового элемента, имеющим координаты старого, но умноженные на коэффициент высоту и ширину.

Всё работает, как надо, если элемент просто добавляется на сцену и сразу после этого я нажимаю на кнопку изменения масштаба, но если же я это делаю после перемещения элемента, то новый добавляется с измененным размером, но в том месте, куда был изначально добавлен старый элемент, т.е. до перемещения.

Элемент добавляю не статически. Вот как я это делаю.

```
void PaintScene::mousePressEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *mouseEvent)
{
    if(mouseEvent->button() != Qt::LeftButton) //если нажали правую кнопку
        return;
    addItem(rect);
    Rect = new QGraphicsRectItem (QRectF());
    Rect->setPen(QPen(Qt::darkCyan, 3));
    addItem(Rect);
    m_isKeyPressed = true;
    x_old = mouseEvent->scenePos().x();
    y_old=mouseEvent->scenePos().y();
}

void PaintScene::mouseMoveEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *mouseEvent)
{
    if(m_isKeyPressed)
    {
        int X, Y, Xmin, Ymin;
        X = qMax(mouseEvent->scenePos().x(), x_old);
        Y = qMax(mouseEvent->scenePos().y(), y_old);
        Xmin = qMin(mouseEvent->scenePos().x(), x_old);
        Ymin = qMin(mouseEvent->scenePos().y(), y_old);
        QRectF newRect (Xmin, Ymin, X-Xmin, Y-Ymin);
        Rect->setRect(newRect);
        Rect->setFlag(QGraphicsRectItem::ItemIsMovable, true);
        Rect->setFlag(QGraphicsRectItem::ItemIsSelectable, true);
    }
}

void PaintScene::mouseReleaseEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *mouseEvent)
{
    if(mouseEvent->button() == Qt::LeftButton)
    {
        update();
        m_isKeyPressed = false;
    }
}
```

Так я создаю новый элемент, который должен замещать старый.

```
bool PaintScene::scaleObject(const qreal Scala)
{
    foreach (QGraphicsItem *item, selectedItems()) {
        QPointF point1 = item->boundingRect().topLeft();
        QPointF point2 = item->boundingRect().bottomRight();
        Angle = item->data(key_angle).toDouble();
        rect = new QGraphicsRectItem();
        addItem(rect);
        rect->setPen(QPen(Qt::darkRed, 3));
        // rect->setRect(point1.x(), point1.y(),(point2.x()-point1.x())*Scala, (point2.y()-point1.y())*Scala);
        rect->setRect(point1.x(), point1.y(), (point2.x()-point1.x())*Scala, (point2.y()-point1.y())*Scala);

        //rect->setPos(0, 0); 
        removeItem(item);
        if (Angle)
        {
            QTransform Transf = rect->transform();
            QPointF p = item->boundingRect().center();

            Transf.translate(p.x(), p.y());
            Transf.rotate(Angle);
            Transf *= QTransform::fromScale(rect->scale(),rect->scale());
            Transf.translate(-p.x(),  -p.y());
            //QPointF point;
            //point = rect->scenePos();
            rect->setTransform(Transf);
            rect->setData(key_angle, Angle);
            //rect->setPos(point.x(), point.y());
        }
        rect->setFlag(QGraphicsRectItem::ItemIsMovable, true);
        rect->setFlag(QGraphicsRectItem::ItemIsSelectable, true);
        rect->update();
        update();
        clearSelection();
    }
    return true;
}
```

Подкиньте какие-нибудь идеи, пожалуйста.

Главный вопрос:

> Почему не сохраняются координаты QGraphicsItem'ов
>   после перемещения, или я чего-то не понимаю?

Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Создаём квадраты на сцене нажатием правой кнопки мыши, перемещаем их при помощи зажатой левой кнопки мыши, выделенный квадрат после нажатия клавиши '+' единожды увеличивается в размере в два раза.

```
#ifndef MAINWIN_H
#define MAINWIN_H

#include <QtWidgets/QMainWindow>
#include <QGraphicsView>
#include <QGraphicsObject>
#include <QKeyEvent>
#include <QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent>

class CustomScene : public QGraphicsScene
{
public:
    void mousePressEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *_ev) override
    {
        if (_ev->button() == Qt::RightButton)
        {
            QGraphicsRectItem* rect = new QGraphicsRectItem(QRectF(0, 0, 50, 50));
            rect->setFlags(QGraphicsItem::ItemIsSelectable | QGraphicsItem::ItemIsMovable);
            addItem(rect);
            rect->setPos(_ev->scenePos());
        }

        QGraphicsScene::mousePressEvent(_ev);
    }

    void keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *_ev)
    {
        if (_ev->key() == Qt::Key::Key_Plus)
        {
            qreal scale = 2;
            foreach(QGraphicsItem *item, selectedItems())
            {
                item->setScale(scale);
                item->update();
            }
        }

        QGraphicsScene::keyPressEvent(_ev);
    }
};

class mainwin : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    mainwin(QWidget *parent = 0)
    {
        QGraphicsView* view_widget = new QGraphicsView();        
        CustomScene* scene = new CustomScene();
        scene->setSceneRect(view_widget->rect());
        view_widget->setScene(scene);
        setCentralWidget(view_widget);
        setFixedSize(640, 480);
    }
};

#endif // MAINWIN_H
```